# Can not resolve getSupportFragmentManager in non fragment class

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to add one of my fragment from ,one of my fragment's adapter holder class onClick ,in oreder to do this i have tried below code;

```
  @Override
public void onClick(View view) {


    try {
        Activity activity = (Activity) context;
        GalleryFragment galleryFragment = new GalleryFragment();
        activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, galleryFragment).commit();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

also tried `getActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, galleryFragment).commit();`

but getting the error can not resolve .getSupportFragmentManager().How to solve this in my case?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you `Activity` to `FragmentActivity`

```
FragmentActivity activity = (FragmentActivity) context;
activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()...
```

Comment: Thank you :) ,silly mistake ,you saved my time,will accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

so it is in your adapter class right?

How about put this in your MainActivity

```
public FragmentManager getFM() {
    return getSupportFragmentManager();
}
```

Then in your adapter class

```
((MainActivity) activity).getFM().beginTransaction()
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, galleryFragment).commit();
```

or

in your MainActivity

```
public void goToFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
}
```

Then in your adapter class

```
((MainActivity) activity).goToFragment(galleryFragment);
```